# How to extract fractional digits of double

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to extact fractional part of double in sql, but without "0." For example:
number: 5.67
int: 5
fact: 67

Comment: How many digits? All of them? There can be plenty. A certain number? Then how to round? This is also quite a strange requirement (and as such, can be poorly supported depending on specifics) -- what's the intended use?

Comment: If this is for money, [you need to use fixed rather than floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency/3730040#3730040).

Comment: @Женя Касьян my answers below have fiddle corrections .Have a check on it!!!!

Answer (score 1):

In most databases, you can use something like this:

```
select cast((x - floor(x)) * 100 as int)
```

In SQL Server, you have other options.  For instance, to get the fractional part, you can use `%`:

```
select (x % 1)
```

To get two digits:

```
select floor(100 * (x % 1)) -- or perhaps round()
```

or:

```
select (x * 100) % 100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 5.67 AS Doubles, CAST(5.67  AS INT) AS Fractional_Only, 
PARSENAME(5.67,1) AS DECIMAL_ONLY
```

Answer (score -1):

this will work in oracle:

```
select substr(to_char(5.67),instr(to_char(5.67),'.')+1) from dual;
```

check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e2ac5e/1074

for mssql :

```
select substring(CONVERT(varchar, 25.65),CHARINDEX('.', CONVERT(varchar, 25.65))+1,5);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/41866

check the last one :

```
select substring(CONVERT(varchar, (15+15)/2.0),
                 CHARINDEX('.', CONVERT(varchar, (15+15)/2.0))+1,1);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/41875

Comment: but i need in MSSQL Server

Comment: is good
but if i use, for example 34, fact=34, but i need fact=0

Comment: @ЖеняКасьян take the column + two times or * 2 and divide it by 2.0 to convert it to double